# : expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token

Tags: c, aes

I am running the programm , which includes reading Hard disk drive ID and ethernet mac ID also Advanced encryption std is used .

when i compile the program with command line "gcc -Wall securiti.c -lcrypto" getting the compilation error.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <linux/hdreg.h>
  #include <net/if.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <sys/ioctl.h>
  #include <openssl/aes.h>
  #include <openssl/rand.h>

  unsigned char aes(char **argv)
  unsigned char* hddid(char *devname);
  unsigned char* macid(void);
   //unsigned char* xor1(char hdd_id,char mac_id);
  unsigned char* char1();
  unsigned char* xor(char c,char d);
  char destroy(char* argv[]);

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   unsigned char *hdd_id;
   unsigned char *mac_id;
   unsigned char c;
   unsigned char d;
   unsigned char e;
   unsigned char c1;
   //unsigned char c2;
   unsigned char h;
   unsigned char m; 
   int i,s; 
   char f;
   //remove(argv[0]);

   if (geteuid() >  0) 
   {
   printf("ERROR: Must be root to use\n");
   exit(1);
   }

   hdd_id = hddid(argv[1]);
   h = hdd_id;
    mac_id =  macid();
   m = mac_id;
   printf("\nHard disk Serial Number A:%.20s\n", hdd_id);
   printf("\nMac Id B: ");
   for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   printf("%x ", mac_id[i]);
   printf("\n");
   int j; /*
   c = xor1(hdd_id,mac_id); 
   printf("\nxor of two id's C=%x\n");*/
   //for(j = 0;j < 6;j++)
   //printf("%x",c[j]);
   c = aes(argv[1]);
   printf("\n%s",aes);
   //printf("\nxor of two ids c=%x\n");
   printf("======================");
   d = char1();
   printf("\nThe value of D=%x\n",d);
   printf("--------------------------");
   e = xor(c,d);
   printf("\nxor of C and D is E=%x\n",e);
   printf("----------------------------");
   FILE* fp;
   fp = fopen("/tmp/mymo.lic", "w");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
   printf("unable to write into a file.\n");
   exit(0);
   }
   fprintf(fp,"%c",e);

   c1 = e-d;
   printf("\nvlaue of c1=%x\n",c1);
   printf("*****************************");

   /* c2 = h + m;
   printf("\nvalue of c2=%x\n",c2);
   */
   if(c1!=c)
   {
    printf("\nThe security key is valid\n");
   }
   else
   {
   printf("\nThe security key is valid\n");
   printf("*****************************\n");
  }
   printf("*****************************\n");
   /*int r;
   if(r<=2)
   {
    printf("Do not run the program more than two times,");
    else       
    remove(argv[0]);
    }

     //s = destroy(argv[0]);
     exit(0);*/
     remove(argv[0]);
     return 0;

     }

     char destroy( char *argv[0])                                       
     {
     int s;
      char file_name[10];
      printf("Enter the file_name:");

      gets(file_name);
       s = remove(file_name);
      if(s==0)
      printf("%s\n",file_name);

      return unlink(argv[0]);
      remove(argv[0]);
     }

      //xor function
      unsigned char* xor(char c,char d)
      {
       char z;
       z = c^d;
       //printf("%x\n",z);
        return z;
       }

      //char1 function
      unsigned char* char1()
       {
       char str[10];
       int i=0;

        printf("\nEnter a string: ");
        scanf("%s",str);
       //printf("%s",str[i]);
        printf("\nASCII values of given string is D:",str);
        while(str[i])
       {
        printf("%d",str[i++]);
         printf("\n");
        }
        return str;
       }
       //xor function
       /* unsigned char* xor1(char hdd_id,char mac_id)
       {

        char y;
        y = hdd_id ^ mac_id;
        //printf("xor c :%x\n",y);
        return y;
        }*/

       //hddid function
       unsigned char* hddid(char *devname)
       {
        static struct hd_driveid hd;
        int fd;

         if ((fd = open(devname, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)) < 0) 
        {
         printf("ERROR: Cannot open device %s\n", devname);
         exit(1);
          }

        if (ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &hd)) 
       {
        perror("ERROR: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY");
        exit(1);
       }
       return hd.serial_no;
       }

        unsigned char* macid(void)
       {
       struct ifreq ifr;
       struct ifconf ifc;
       char buf[1024];
       int success = 0;

        int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
        if (sock == -1) 
       { 
         perror("sock:");
       }

        ifc.ifc_len = sizeof(buf);
        ifc.ifc_buf = buf;

        if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) == -1)
       { 
        perror("ioctl:");
       }

       struct ifreq* it = ifc.ifc_req;
       const struct ifreq* const end = it + (ifc.ifc_len / sizeof(struct ifreq));

       for (it; it != end; ++it) {
       strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, it->ifr_name);
       if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) == 0) {
       if (! (ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_LOOPBACK)) { // don't count loopback
        if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr) == 0) {
       success = 1;
        break;
       }
       }
       }
       else {
       perror("ioctl:");
       }
       }

       static unsigned char mac_address[6];
       int i;
       if (success) memcpy(mac_address, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6);
       return mac_address;
       }

        unsigned char aes(char **argv)
       {
       int i;
       int keylength;
       printf("Give a key length [only 128 or 192 or 256]:\n");
       scanf("%d", &keylength);

        /* generate a key with a given length */
         unsigned char aes_key[keylength];
        memset(aes_key, 0, sizeof(aes_key));
            if (!RAND_bytes(aes_key, keylength))
        {
        //printf("girish\n");
        exit(-1);
        }
         aes_key[keylength-1] = '\0';
         int inputslength;
         printf("Give an input's length:\n");
         scanf("%d", &inputslength);
         /* generate input with a given length */
          unsigned char aes_input[inputslength+1];
         memset(aes_input, '0', sizeof(aes_input));
         aes_input[inputslength] = '\0';
        /*printf("original:\t");
         for(i=0; i<inputslength; i++)
        {
         printf("%c ", aes_input[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");*/

         /* init vector */
        unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
        if (!RAND_bytes(iv, AES_BLOCK_SIZE));
        {
         exit(-1);
         }

         //printf("AES_BLOCK_SIZE = %d\n", AES_BLOCK_SIZE); 
         // aes block size is 16 bytes = 128 bits
         AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
          unsigned char enc_out[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
          unsigned char dec_out[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
          // so i can do with this aes-cbc-128 aes-cbc-192 aes-cbc-256
            AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, keylength, &enc_key);
            AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, inputslength, &enc_key, iv,                    AES_ENCRYPT);
          printf("girish121\n");
        AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key, keylength, &dec_key);
        printf("girish12\n");
        AES_decrypt(enc_out, dec_out, &dec_key);
        printf("original:\t");
        for(i=0;*(aes_input+i)!=0x00;i++)
        {
         printf("%X ",*(aes_input+i));
        //AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key,keylength,&dec_key);
          printf("\nencrypted:\t");
          printf("\ng\n");
          }
         for(i=0;*(enc_out+i)!=0x00;i++)
        {
            printf("%X ",*(enc_out+i));
            printf("\ng1\n");
            printf("\ndecrypted:\t");
         }
         for(i=0;*(dec_out+i)!=0x00;i++)
         {
             printf("%X ",*(dec_out+i));
             printf("\ng3");
             printf("\n");
          }
           return 0;
         }
```

Comment: can anyone show some light on this error .

Comment: semicolon all your statements?

Comment: When you have question about compilation error, always include **complete** error output.

Comment: Post line no also at which this error occured.

Comment: You might be missing a semicolon somewhere before the error, or missing a closing brace or parenthesis or something else. You should look at the code above the error.

Comment: In this case it's a missing semicolon very early in the program. Do look at the function prototypes at the top again.

Comment: You need to terminate the function declaration on line 14 with a semicolon. Voting to close as "not very useful minor error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semicolon missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/hdreg.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

unsigned char aes(char **argv)       //unsigned char aes(char **argv);
```